# Цикл foreach и переменные

Tags: циклы, foreach, php

Создаю переменные через цикл foreach:

```
foreach($user_data as $key => $value) {
 ${$key} = $value;
}
```

Всё работает. Например $login выводит логин пользователя. Но как добавить префикс user?

`$user_{$key} = $value;` - **не** **работает**. Как заставить работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, так лучше не делать, но подумайте немного - ведь $key - строка, что нужно сделать, чтобы добавить к ней префикс ?

Comment: @eicto, не догоняю как правильно добавить. Подскажите, пожалуйста. И почему кстати так не делать?

Comment: а зачем плодить переменные ? чем массив вообще хуже ? по нему и искать проще и преобразовывать данные. а так вам надо будет всё время помнить какие значения $key бывают, чтобы обратиться к значению переменной.

Comment: @eicto, это просто вывод полей из таблицы users в MySQL. Не очень-то хочется проделывать что-то типа этого: $user_login = $user_data['login']; $user_first_name = $user_data['first_name']; и т.д

Comment: @ModaL, так а зачем вообще вводить `$user_login`?

Answer (score 1):

```
${'user_'.$key} = $value;
```